# Replace all <br> tag with space in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Having trouble with very simple thing, 
How to properly replace all `< br>` and `<br>` in the string with the empty space?

This is what I'm trying to use, but I'm receiving the same string.:

```
var finalStr = replaceAll(replaceAll(scope.ItemsList[i].itemDescr.substring(0, 27), "<", " "), "br>", " ");
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Comment: Your code already replaces `<br>`...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can achieve that using this:

```
str = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi,' ');
```

This will match:

- `<br` matches the characters `<br` literally (case insensitive)
- `\s*` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`
- Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `\/?` matches the character `/` literally
- Quantifier: `?` Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `>` matches the characters `>` literally
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
- `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of `[a-zA-Z]`)

#### SNIPPET BELOW

```js
let str = "This<br />sentence<br>output<BR/>will<Br/>have<BR>0 br";
str = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, ' ');
console.log(str)
```

Comment: @user1935987 you are wrong, `g` modifier is global.

Comment: I like much more `str.replace(/<br \/>/g,'&nbsp;')`