# replace br tags in html with space comma after putting through python beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

br /> (without.) tag between each line for example
29 BOSWALL PARKWAY
EDINBURGH
EH5 2BR. They tags disappear when i write  in this text editor.

when i put through beautiful soup output looks like 29 BOSWALL PARKWAYEDINBURGHEH5 2BR

does anyone know a good way to generate a comma space were were the tags are? Many thanks in advance.

I've tried the following based on other examples read

1st  method generate SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal error
2nd method AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replaceAll'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results'

baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

session = requests.session()

response = session.get(url)

# content of search page in soup 
html = soup(response.content,"lxml")

Address = LeftBlockData[3].get_text().strip()
#Address_1 = Address.replace("<br>,",");
Address_1 = Address.replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]"," ");

print (Address1)
```

Comment: Using `replace` I assume you need to escape the `<>` Hope this helps ► http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815103/replace-all-br-with-space-in-javascript - You should be able to amend the regex slightly to look for the exact format of `<br />`, `<br>` etc.. you are having and add a `,` to the space.

Comment: thanks for the reply, added the following line                                    Address_1 = Address.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi,'&nbsp;');     also tried without the ; at the end but both times got an invalid syntax errror. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

`<br>` is line break, we usually do not contain such control character in the data, but you can use a list to contain all the line:

```
In [72]: table = html.find('div', class_='table')


In [77]: for row in table.find_all('div', class_='row table-row'):
    ...:     print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))
    ...:     
    ...:     
    ...:     
    ...:     
['Ref No.', '110B60329']
['Office', 'LOTHIAN VJB']
['Description', 'STORE']
['Property Address', '29 BOSWALL PARKWAY', 'EDINBURGH', 'EH5 2BR']
['Proprietor', 'SCOTTISH MIDLAND CO-OP SOCIETY LTD.']
['Tenant', 'PROPRIETOR']
['Occupier']
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but don't would prefer not to get into creating all table output.