# I replace all tags `<br>`, with a newline

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I replace all tags `<br>`, with a newline, in the incoming text?

Example: I get the text from server: *Text text text `<br>` text text text.*

I am expecting the following result:  
*Text text text text 
 text text text.*

p.s.  I use react-native

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the text? If you drop text like that into the DOM as HTML, the browser will give you a line break; that's what `<br>` is for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469570/how-can-i-insert-a-line-break-into-a-text-component-in-react-native hope this will help

Comment: Why tag this as reactjs if you are using react-native

Comment: @Pointy The OP says he uses react-native. Therefor, it seems to me he doesn't want the end result to be runnable in a browser.

Comment: @David ah good point

Comment: David You are right!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all <br> tag with space in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815103/replace-all-br-tag-with-space-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via `String.prototype.replace`:

```js
var incoming = 'Foo <br> Bar <br> Baz';

function brToNl(text) {
  return text.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
}

console.log(brToNl(incoming));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
var str = 'Text text text \<br> text text text.' 
var replaced = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
console.log(replaced);
```